# show reviews for current_user only using devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I am creating an app where a member signs up and can create a post, and users can write reviews on that post without needing to sign up, the reviews have their own index view. I have searched around, but cannot find an answer as to how to only show the current user reviews specific to their posts. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

I have the following associations:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :posts
 has_many :reviews, through: :posts
end

class Post < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :user
end

class Review < ApplicationRecord
 belongs_to :post
end
```

In the Reviews controller index method I have the following code which works well, but it is showing reviews to all users, as only the logged in user needs to be able to see all reviews for a specific post.

```
def index
 post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])
 @reviews = post.reviews
end
```

**Is it possible to use an if/else statement in the view using the user_id and post_id and relate that to the reviews, so that only the owner of the post can see all related reviews?**

Answer (score 0):

Suppose your Review Model has a column created_by_id to store the user id who creates that review.

Try like this

```
def index
 post = Post.friendly.find(params[:post_id])

 #Write where condition to filter current_user reviews
 @reviews = post.reviews.where(created_by_id: current_user_id)
end
```

Comment: The issue I have is that the reviewer does not need to sign up, so the database would not have a record of the user that created the review, I need a way in which I can reference the user that created the post with the reviews belonging to that post. So if the current_user is the Post creator he needs to be able to see all reviews created for their post.